# Include boolean params with g:include are passed as Strings to the included view

Tags: grails, grails-3.3.x

I don't know if the following change is an issue or it is intended.

```
<g:include view="line.gsp" params="['label':'test', 'progress':false]"/>
```

Then the expression in line.gsp aways evaluates to true, because the type of the 'progress' param is String, not Boolean.

```
  class is: ${params.progress.getClass()}
  <g:if test="${params.progress}">
   this should not be displayed
 </g:if>
```

Note that the same is applicable for other types, not just Boolean.
I am using grails 3.3.8 
This didn't happen in grails 2.5.2.

I didn't find anything about this online so that's why I am asking here. Thanks.

**Edit:**

As suggested by Daniel, I've tried with grails 3.3.2 also. 
I just created an app with grails create-app and modified the existing index.gsp to include line.gsp, as shown in the code above.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This is working as expected in grails 3.3.2 at least.  I just tested your exact example and `${params.progress.getClass()}` was Boolean, and it evaluated properly in an if block.  Perhaps something else is going on?  Any chance you're already passing a `progress` param into the parent view?

Comment: Hmm, I've tried with 3.3.8, 3.0.0 and grails 2.5.2. I created the apps from scratch with grails create-app. I just created a simple line.gsp file containing the code from the question and then modified the existing index.gsp file to include the line.gsp file. I didn't do any other change. Weird.

Comment: What happens if you output `${params.progress}` in your line.gsp?  Or `${params.progress.getClass()}`?

Comment: it shows true for both grails 2 and 3, but it shows java.lang.String() for grails 3 while for grails 2 it is java.lang.Boolean. That's how I noticed that progress is interpreted as a String, because initially I had a different error in the gsp that was actually caused by this. I will try it with grails 3.3.2 also. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel I've tried with grails 3.3.2 also, even on a different system, and I get the same results. I eddited my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Worth just looking at the code in `org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.UrlMappingTagLib` for the include closure, it may be obvious, or not

Comment: Yeah, I did. I ended up using <g:render template model=[..] instead of <g:include.

Comment: Note that you can `g:include` a view with a `model` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you have already found a workaround to this, but it was bothering me that your code was not working the same way mine was, so I decided to investigate a bit further in case anyone else runs into this issue.

As other people here have mentioned, `params.anything` will typically return a String value.  This is because params are typically encoded as URI parameters (like ?progress=false) and not autoboxed into any other type.  (This is perfectly reasonable; there would be no good way for Grails to know what type they should be.)  However, it is possible (and occasionally reasonable) to render your view or template from a controller like `render view: whatever, model: [your: model, params: params]` where you specifically include params in the model.  (Perhaps you have a lot of parameters that you do not need to individually recreate in the model.)  In this case, the params map will exist as both URI parameters (?progress=false) and page-scoped model entry (params: [progress: Boolean.FALSE]).  Page scope takes priority over URI parameters, and so your types will be preserved.

In my testing, I added your code to an existing page where I was already passing params into the model, and so type was preserved for a newly added parameter as well.  (Note that once params are in page scope, they're there for included templates or views as well.)  Consequently, I saw progress type of Boolean, while in a basic example it would be type String.

TL/DR: either assume params are strings, or explicitly include params in your page-scoped model when rendering.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. When you are calling `params.something`, you are actually accessing GrailsParameterMap which is a Map. So your condition actually evaluates as Map->get() which will be Object->toString() and of course it is true cause it's not null and not empty. So the solution will be the following:

```
<g:if test="${params.getBoolean("progress")}">
   this should not be displayed
</g:if>
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. My only concern was how come this was changed in grails 3.

Comment: Why do you believe that GrailsParameterMap necessarily returns a String value?

Comment: I mention in this condition only. You can check by: ${params.progress?.getClass()} which will print: class java.lang.String. Yes: the GrailsParameterMap can store diff type of Object in value on other scenarios as always.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this as follows

```
<g:if test="${params.progress && params.progress == 'false'}">
   this should not be displayed
 </g:if>
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. My only concern was how come this was changed in grails 3. Migrating an app from grails 2 to grails 3 involves changing all such occurrences that previusly worked in grails 2.